# fopen and uploading images from URL

Tags: php, image, fopen

I want to upload images from URL but some image URLs are strangely formatted (like below)

How can I upload these images from user side without using fopen? Because allowing client side fopen is  big security risk.

Here is an example of image URL causing the problem:
https://drpem3xzef3kf.cloudfront.net/photos/pets/31990459/1/?bust=1429848480&width=632&no_scale_up=1

Please help. thank you

Comment: Use cURL, return the site content and write it to a file then save as .jpg since it's already having a content of an image

Comment: this image 
https://drpem3xzef3kf.cloudfront.net/photos/pets/31990459/1/?bust=1429848480&width=632&no_scale_up=1
closed from curl requests completely, it checks http headers and not allowed to download it for robots

Comment: Well, with my simple curl, I'm accessing it from here via curl